# Biome parse throws an error without specifying the rule

Tags: jsx

I have a js project that has some files with a `return` statmement outside functions (`.jsx` files).

Using biome as linter/formatter it throws an error in vscode as you can see:

[image]

I'd like to disable that rule, but without knowing the name (like the second one "noSvgWithoutTitle"), I'm not really sure how to do it...

How can I fix this?